# How to Create Custom Variables inside WYSIWYG editor in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-variable

I have created a Custom field under `Stores->Configuration->General.`
I need to use that field as Custom variable inside `WYSIWYG editor` when **Insert Variable** option is clicked.

I don't Know how to proceed forward after creating those fields..Please Help me out..

Thanks in advance.